# Keras Lambda Layer and py_function gives error Cannot iterate over a shape with unknown rank

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am trying to build a model that among its implementation that it takes two text inputs and get a one-hot vector based on one of the indices of the input.

I created the following custom functions:

```
def get_index(text, word):
    # get index
    index = get_expression_indices(text, word)
    id_seq = []
    for i in range(70): #length of the text
        if i == index :
            id_seq.insert(i, 1)
        else:
            id_seq.insert(i, 0)
    return np.array(id_seq)

def get_index_tensor(input):
    return tf.py_function(get_index, [input[0], input[1]], tf.string)
```

And here is a dummy model

```
# input layers
input_text_1 = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='string')
input_text_2 = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='string')
context = Lambda(emb_utils.get_index_tensor, output_shape=(None,))([input_text_1, input_text_2])
model = Model(inputs=[input_text_1, input_text_2], outputs=context)
```

I get an error: `ValueError: Cannot iterate over a shape with unknown rank.`
The output shape should be (batch_size, 70, 1)
When I remove `output_sape=(None,)` I get `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`
Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the shape of py_function's output:

```
def get_index_tensor(input):
    result = tf.py_function(get_index, [input[0], input[1]], tf.string)
    result.set_shape((None, 70, 1))
    return result
```